# Grails Hibernate Session or Spring Transaction destroying Domain validation errors

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, grails, grails-services

So my problem is that my validation errors are being deleted from my domain object before I can render them on the page. I thought I had fixed this error in the past, but it has crept up on me again.

Here is a look at my original implementation. The errors were being cleared when `tripService.stepData(trip)` was being called.

**Edit- I should not that I only experienced this issue when the page adds to a hasMany relationship.**

Controller -

```
    Trip trip = tripService.savePrePaymentInfo(params)

    if (trip.hasErrors()) {
        render(view: "step4", model: tripService.stepData(trip))
    }
    else {
        redirect(action: trip.status.action, id:trip.id)
    }
```

Service -

```
Map stepData(Trip trip)
{
    Map returnSet = [:]
    returnSet.status = Status.findAllByActionNotEqual("review")
    returnSet.trip = trip
    returnSet
}
```

So I did some reading online and someone one on a forum post like 2 years ago said there was something in hibernate..possible bug... I don't know, but their suggestion worked. The suggestion was to wrap the controller in a `withTransaction`:

```
Trip.withTransaction {

//Controller code here

}
```

This has been working for me fine. The issue now is that I have a taglib in my view that calls `tripService` again. When that call is being made it is now clearing my validation errors. This is getting really frustrating. Does anyone have ANY idea on what I can do to resolve this?

Edit: Adding service method being called from taglib:

```
String findBannerName(Long pidm, String format = 'LFMI')
{
    "abc"
    //It really doesnt matter what is here - tried just returning this string and it produced the issue        
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's because your service is transactional, even if `stepData()` isn't? What happens if you declare setpData as not transactional?

Comment: Can you declare service methods non transactional without having the entire service that way?

Comment: I think that the only way that works is to set the service to transactional false and annotate the methods that must be transactional.

Comment: Alright  I'm giving it a go - will report soon

Comment: Ok I only marked the methods that update the database as transactional and it appears to be working. Put your comment in the answer and I'll mark it as accepted, however, I would really like to know WHY this is happening.

Comment: With completion of `savePrePaymentInfo` a transaction is completed. When the same service class is re-used from the tag lib (calling `stepData()` which is transactional), a new hibernate session and a new transaction is initiated. Hibernate fetches the `Trip` and forgets about the errors it had earlier. I might not bet on this behavior but I was in the same page as @SérgioMichels looking at the question.

Comment: Well the problem with that is the method that was being called from the TagLib in tripService had nothing to do with the trip. It wasnt being passed as a parameter or anything. Also before I wrapped the controller with a `withTransaction`, I tried removing the trip from the `stepData()` method and it was still the same result.

Comment: Maybe because Trip was marked to be flushed, and since your other service is transactional, your trip instance was flushed? You can try calling `trip.discard()` to avoid this instance to be flushed, or wrap your service call in a `withNewSession` closure (in the taglib).

Comment: I get other exceptions (lazy loading) when discarding the trip...lol

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the trip.errors property is populated in the first place?

Also, which tripService method are you calling in the taglib?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Added the method for you to the question.

Comment: Have a look at the wording and example code snippets in http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/services.html, Validation Errors and Rollback: "To re-render the same view that a transaction was rolled back in you can re-associate the errors with a refreshed instance before rendering".

Comment: I see that example, how would it work for new objects that don't have an ID? Also... just an opinion... it's really really dumb if it has to be done that way.

Comment: In the example you get the errors from the validation exception. Also you said that this behavior occurs only when adding to a hasMany relationship. Any chance the validation errors would reside in the  referenced domain object (hasMany collection member)?

Comment: No there is no chance. After the validation exception, it does a .read(id). For new objects there is no ID.